# How to use a argument with space in a batch file

Tags: command-line, parameters, command-line-arguments

i needed to pass some arguments to a exe, but one of the argument was having a space

the code is

```
myApp.exe arg1 arg 2
```

This created a problem as the second argument was split into two.The work around i did was like

```
myApp.exe arg1 'arg 2'
```

this helped in passing argument with space as a single argument

Comment: This is hardly a batch question, since it is more about using the command prompt than scripting a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose them in double quotes:

myApp.exe arg1 "arg 2"